# Protecting php page from being opened in browser only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, permissions

I am working on a live weather data page. Our weather module outputs the data in CSV and stores it on my webserver. I then use a PHP script to translate the CSV into an array and then i encode it in JSON and output it so that my jQuery Ajax script can call it every so often to get the latest data and update the page. This is working great so far.

My question is, how can i prevent the URL used to retrieve the JSON (the URL of the aforementioned PHP script) to be opened and viewed in a browser? I tried adjusting the permissions, but to no success.

Thanks in advance to any who are willing to help.

Comment: Why would you prevent anyone from seeing url in browser?

Comment: I'd suggest genereting a random key on the serverside, and placing that key in the HTML somewhere for javascript to fetch it. Then send that key with every ajax request and check if it matches the key previously generated on the serverside, and only print the JSON if it does. It's not really secure, but it it's fairly simply to do and will make it a lot harder for anyone to display the JSON directly. Another way would be to just check the requesting URL for your site etc.

Comment: It's a good idea but it's not really stopping anything. View source and get the key and call the URL. It's a bit less trivial but still very doable.

Comment: @SimonGermain - It's not really secure, but if you hide the key in some random data attribute and minify your javascript, someone would have to be very interested to figure it out, and it will stop scraping in most instances. If you set up the sending of the key globally in jQuery's ajaxsetup you would'nt even have to include the key in the data sent with the regular ajax call, making it even harder to figure out.

Comment: I'll flag this as helpful because it's a good point :)

Comment: @yakxxx, we thought about licensing the data at some point and only showing a couple of data items. I though there could be a simple way to do this, but i guess im just gonna have to make a separate file with those specific items for on the page.

Comment: @adeneo a really simple peek in the "net" tab of firebug shows all the information too. This is obfuscation, and poor one at that. It could be hidden a little better by making the call from a flash or java app that encrypts it. But even that is not "secure".

Comment: @berkes - Nothing is really secure when it comes to this, but the above solution would ensure some randomness that will make it hard for regular users to figure out how to view the JSON. I've seen variations on this using a key with a timestamp and a salt, making it only valid for a few seconds, solutions that also uses the session to make sure the user is on your page, solutions using algorithems to move the key around on the page in certain patterns etc. You can make a pretty complicated solution that would be hard to figure out (but not impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of (reliably) identifying a browser as anything that is not some form of "Authentication-Token" can be faked. The server relies on the client to be honest.

You can detect if a request is an ajax request tho. Here is a link to one way of doing it:

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

This is how he does it:

```
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* special ajax here */
    die($content);
}
```

You will want to reverse the statements in the if since it `die()`s when the request IS ajax.

There are other ways of detecting ajax, none of which are 100% secure, including you setting a GET variable that helps you identify an ajax call (but that get variable can also be sent via the browser via the address line so well... you get the picture)

Comment: That script is very dependent on the server implementing that HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH. If you control the web server and able to make sure this is present, you're golden :D

Comment: You probably want to send a header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden') instead of just die() though.

Comment: You can make the ajax request add any GET-Data you like.. you can not be sure tho that it isn't a browser!

Comment: @SimonGermain and Gung Foo, I do have complete control over the web server and this feature seems to be present and working very well. One last question: Now that I have limited from only being used through ajax, can I make sure that only my domain accesses it? (if that makes any sense)

Comment: Browsers do this automatically. It would be harder to turn that off. ;) check this out: http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Answer (score 3):

There's no real way of doing that, since the Ajax call also comes from the browser. There's no real difference between a proper browser call and an Ajax call. A GET call is a GET call.

*EDIT*

As per @Adeneo's suggestion, implementing a pseudo-security, through some kind of key, would be a good way of making it harder for people to view the page, even though there's no way of literally blocking the call.

Also, adding a header to your Ajax call and verifying the presence of that header in your backend script makes it a bit harder to spoof.

Another idea would be that, if that service would be called only once per page view, you could setup a key in your javascript, provided by your server, to append to your ajax call. When the server gets called, the key provided becomes invalid after use, preventing someone from calling the service with the same key twice.

Comment: To avoid scraping (I assume this is OPs goal) you could additionally implement thresholds based on session and IP. Like: can only make one call every 5 minutes, per IP/Session.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: you could implement a simple [Browser Sniffing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). Or search for far more advanced methods.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if ($browser[parent] == "whatever-identifies-clients-that-have-access") {
  //Code to output jSon here.
}
else {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}
```

But note that this is not security. At the very most, it throws up a barrier; but preventing is impossible.

**Edit** This assumes the client is not a browser, I wrongly assumed a (mobile) client of some sorts was accessing the JSON. When it is a browser, you cannot deny access. At all. AJAX comes from that browser too.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work since the Ajax call comes from the browser. Wouldn't browsecap still see this as a browser?

Comment: You are right, Simon. I misread the Q, and thought the JSON was consumed by some application (mobile, desktop client).